# how do I set up next.config.js so that the class name only contains hash?

Tags: css, webpack, next.js

I use next.js and css modules. node-sass and @zeit/next-sass I don't want to use. Can you please tell us how to configure next.config.js so that the class name only contains hash?
package.json:

```
{
  "name": "learn-starter",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "next": "9.3.5",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "16.13.1",
    "sass": "^1.26.8"
  }
}
```

[image example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fxk0S.png)

Comment: For webpack 5: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66744765/edit-css-loaders-localidentname-in-nextjs-to-hide-class-names-from-users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

```
const regexEqual = (x, y) =>
  x instanceof RegExp &&
  y instanceof RegExp &&
  x.source === y.source &&
  x.global === y.global &&
  x.ignoreCase === y.ignoreCase &&
  x.multiline === y.multiline;

module.exports = {
  webpack(config) {
    const sassRules = config.module.rules
      .find((rule) => typeof rule.oneOf === "object")
      .oneOf.find(
        (rule) =>
          rule.sideEffects === false &&
          regexEqual(rule.test, /\.module\.(scss|sass)$/)
      );

    sassRules.use = sassRules.use.map((rule) =>
      rule.loader.includes("css-loader/dist")
        ? {
            ...rule,
            options: {
              ...rule.options,
              modules: {
                ...rule.modules,
                localIdentName: "[hash:base64:5]",
              },
            },
          }
        : rule
    );

    return config;
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve class name that only contains hash, you have to follow the below naming convention for your css files.

Next.js supports CSS Modules using the [name].module.css file naming convention. Refer to the below example,

First, create components/Button.module.css with the following content:

```
.error {
  color: white;
  background-color: red;
}
```

Then, create components/Button.js, importing and using the above CSS file:

```
import styles from './Button.module.css'

export function Button() {
  return (
    <button
      type="button"
      // Note how the "error" class is accessed as a property on the imported
      // `styles` object.
      className={styles.error}
    >
      Destroy
    </button>
  )
}
```

CSS Modules are an optional feature and are only enabled for files with the .module.css extension

However, you might see class names that contains only hash; when you run production build (npm run build), as for dev builds (npm start) it may not do the full hash only names.