# How to hash CSS class names in Nextjs?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, next.js, css-modules, css-loader

How can I edit `localIdentName` field of `css-loader` in Webpack configuration in Nextjs so that I can hash/hide/obfuscate css class names?

The example below is from the New York Times. Note the class names:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no build in support in `Nextjs` to pass custom configuration to `Webpack` loaders. But we can work around it by using `next.config.js`.

First, create `next.config.js` in the root of your project directory.

**For Nextjs 11**

```
module.exports = {
  webpack(config, { buildId, dev, isServer, defaultLoaders, webpack }) {
    config.module.rules[3].oneOf.forEach((moduleLoader, i) => {
      Array.isArray(moduleLoader.use) &&
        moduleLoader.use.forEach((l) => {
          if (
            l.loader.includes("\\css-loader") &&
            !l.loader.includes("postcss-loader")
          ) {
            const { getLocalIdent, ...others } = l.options.modules;

            l.options = {
              ...l.options,
              modules: {
                ...others,
                localIdentName: "[hash:base64:6]",
              },
            };
          }
        });
    });
    return config;
  },
};
```

**For Next.js 10.2 or a newer version:**

```
module.exports = {
  webpack(config, { buildId, dev, isServer, defaultLoaders, webpack }) {
    config.module.rules[3].oneOf.forEach((moduleLoader, i) => {
      Array.isArray(moduleLoader.use) &&
        moduleLoader.use.forEach((l) => {
          if (
            l.loader.includes("\\css-loader") &&
            !l.loader.includes("postcss-loader")
          ) {
            const { getLocalIdent, ...others } = l.options.modules;

            l.options = {
              ...l.options,
              modules: {
                ...others,
                localIdentName: "[hash:base64:6]",
              },
            };
          }
        });
    });
    return config;
  },
};
```

**Otherwise use this:**

```
module.exports = {
  webpack(config, { buildId, dev, isServer, defaultLoaders, webpack }) {
    config.module.rules[1].oneOf.forEach((moduleLoader, i) => {
      Array.isArray(moduleLoader.use) &&
        moduleLoader.use.forEach((l) => {
          if (
            l.loader.includes('\\css-loader') &&
            !l.loader.includes('postcss-loader')
          ) {
            const { getLocalIdent, ...others } = l.options.modules;

            l.options = {
              ...l.options,
              modules: {
                ...others,
                localIdentName: '[hash:base64:6]',
              },
            };
          }
        });
    });
    return config;
  },
};
```

If you want to hash the class names **only in production**, you can use `process.env.NODE_ENV` with an `if` statement. Like this:

```
module.exports = {
  webpack(config, { buildId, dev, isServer, defaultLoaders, webpack }) {
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
      ...
      ...

      return config;
    } else {
      return config;
    }
  },
};
```

Comment: does anybody know how this should look for webpack 5?

Comment: @jebbie Edited the answer. Check it out.

Comment: @user9408899 just tested it and it outputs the css with hashed name, but the html is still the same, so the classnames do not match between html and css, do you have any idea?

Comment: any solution for next 12?

Comment: This answer is awesome!

Answer (score 27):

None of the answers on this thread will work on newer Next.js versions (`v11.1.3-canary.2` and above), because in [PR#28529](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/pull/28529), the Next.js team has switched to a customized version of [`css-loader`](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/e49829bb8e8f19840c898ddfb7397eda32454b47/packages/next/build/webpack/loaders/css-loader/src/utils.js) that has no [`defaultGetLocalIdent`](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader/blob/aea023d999b213396aa1a06866e82fb4059921b4/src/utils.js#L314), nor does it checks if `getLocalIndent` is [`null`](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader/blob/aea023d999b213396aa1a06866e82fb4059921b4/src/utils.js#L726) or [`undefined`](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader/blob/aea023d999b213396aa1a06866e82fb4059921b4/src/utils.js#L708).

Any solution that ultimately removes `getLocalIdent` from the loader configuration will lead to `TypeError: getLocalIdent is not a function`. In other words, it is now mandatory to provide a function as `getLocalIdent`. Here is an example:

```js
const path = require('path');
const loaderUtils = require('loader-utils');

// based on https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/992c46e63bef20d7ab7e40131667ed3debaf67de/packages/next/build/webpack/config/blocks/css/loaders/getCssModuleLocalIdent.ts
const hashOnlyIdent = (context, _, exportName) =>
  loaderUtils
    .getHashDigest(
      Buffer.from(
        `filePath:${path
          .relative(context.rootContext, context.resourcePath)
          .replace(/\\+/g, '/')}#className:${exportName}`,
      ),
      'md4',
      'base64',
      6,
    )
    .replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9-_]/g, '_')
    .replace(/^(-?\d|--)/, '_$1');

module.exports = {
  webpack(config, { dev }) {
    const rules = config.module.rules
      .find((rule) => typeof rule.oneOf === 'object')
      .oneOf.filter((rule) => Array.isArray(rule.use));

    if (!dev)
      rules.forEach((rule) => {
        rule.use.forEach((moduleLoader) => {
          if (
            moduleLoader.loader?.includes('css-loader') &&
            !moduleLoader.loader?.includes('postcss-loader')
          )
            moduleLoader.options.modules.getLocalIdent = hashOnlyIdent;

            // earlier below statements were sufficient:
            // delete moduleLoader.options.modules.getLocalIdent;
            // moduleLoader.options.modules.localIdentName = '[hash:base64:6]';
        });
      });

    return config;
  },
};
```

---

#### This works on Next v12 and v13 (without TurboPack) too.

[Demo](https://github.com/brc-dd/next-hash-classnames):

*While development -*

[image]

*On production -*

[image]

[Demo with Experimental App Directory](https://github.com/brc-dd/next-hash-classnames/blob/with-appdir):

[image]

Comment: I love you. What a superb, up-to-date, concise and informative answer.

Comment: Does this work for Next 12 ?

Comment: @agoumi yes it does.

Comment: @brc-dd Thank you for the answer, is there a way for a classname like this ClassName="relative flex flex-col" that uses Tailwindcss class naming to be hashed with having to create it's own class seperatly in a css file with "@ apply"?

Comment: @agoumi For that you can use some 3rd party solution like [twin.macro](https://github.com/ben-rogerson/twin.macro).

Comment: @agoumi Here's a great example that helped me out setting up twin.macro for obfuscating tailwind CSS (with next js) in production - https://github.com/ben-rogerson/twin.examples/tree/master/next-styled-components#getting-started

Source: https://www.reddit.com/r/nextjs/comments/r9dp2c/comment/hq8zdxu/

Comment: Why doesn't this work for Tailwind CSS classes?

Comment: This is not working for me with next 12.1.6

Comment: @MichaelSherrisCaley Please try the linked demo. It is working fine for me on the latest version. [Ref.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qipGn.jpg)

Comment: This worked for me on nextjs 12.2.0 but I needed to replace + and / with _ from the final hash. Here's my full file if anyone want's to try: https://gist.github.com/herlon214/7da6a39b885014a5d5f51716f6530ce4

Comment: @BharadwajGiridhar Can you share the config files?

Comment: @agoumi did you get it working with Tailwind CSS?

Comment: Does this work for third-party libraries and their CSS classnames ? @brc-dd

Comment: @shivamragnar No. Works only for CSS modules.

Comment: @brc-dd you have any idea, how do i hash the classnames in 3rd party libraries? I am using SwiperJS with NextJs. I am kinda stuck with with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74205301/hash-uglify-minify-css-classnames-of-external-libraries-in-next-js

Comment: Does not work with next.js 13

Comment: @mayank1513 Check out the linked [repo](https://github.com/brc-dd/next-hash-classnames), it is working fine on Next.js 13 too. Are you sure you're looking the production build not the dev server? Also, note that it won't work with TurboPack, in case you're trying it's alpha.

Comment: I am using app directory no turbopack. It does not build, throws errors

Comment: Here is the error logs - https://stackoverflow.com/q/74677233/9640177

Comment: @brc-dd can you look at this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/68750996/9640177 . are comments the culprits? If so can you help edit the script

Comment: @mayank1513 can you test this: https://github.com/brc-dd/next-hash-classnames/blob/with-appdir/next.config.js ?

Answer (score 2):

For those who use Next.js v13 and the accepted answer doesn't work. You have to change a little bit the moduleLoader condition:

```
if (
    moduleLoader.loader?.includes('css-loader') &&
    !moduleLoader.loader?.includes('postcss-loader') &&
    moduleLoader.options !== undefined &&
    moduleLoader.options.modules !== undefined
) {
```

Answer (score 0):

**This worked for me using Next.js 11:**

```js
module.exports = {
        webpack: (config, { buildId, dev, isServer, defaultLoaders, webpack }) => {
        config.module.rules[3].oneOf.forEach((moduleLoader, i) => {
          Array.isArray(moduleLoader.use) &&
            moduleLoader.use.forEach((l) => {
              if (
                l.loader.includes('\\css-loader') &&
                !l.loader.includes('postcss-loader')
              ) {
                const { getLocalIdent, ...others } = l.options.modules;
    
                l.options = {
                  ...l.options,
                  modules: {
                    ...others,
                    localIdentName: '[hash:base64:6]',
                  },
                };
              }
            });
        });
          return config;
      },
    };
```