# next.js npm module comment giving an error

Tags: reactjs, syntax, next.js

This is my error

```
10:03:56.049    ./components/navbar.js
10:03:56.049    13:33  Warning: img elements must have an alt prop, either with meaningful text, or an empty string for decorative images.  jsx-a11y/alt-text
10:03:56.049    39:33  Warning: img elements must have an alt prop, either with meaningful text, or an empty string for decorative images.  jsx-a11y/alt-text
10:03:56.049    Need to disable some ESLint rules? Learn more here: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/eslint#disabling-rules
10:03:56.051    info  - Creating an optimized production build...
10:04:04.307    Failed to compile.
10:04:04.308    HookWebpackError: Unexpected '/'. Escaping special characters with \ may help.
10:04:04.308    > Build error occurred
10:04:04.309    Error: > Build failed because of webpack errors
10:04:04.309        at /vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/build/index.js:15:924
10:04:04.309        at async Span.traceAsyncFn (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/telemetry/trace/trace.js:6:584)
10:04:04.333    Error: Command "npm run build" exited with 1
```

At first I thought it was coming from `navbar.js` but I don't see any "special characters" there, here is my navbar.js: https://pastebin.com/8XFUtL5A

So then I went and checked `node_modules/next/dist/telemetry/trace/trace.js:6:584` and I found a lot of comments there: https://pastecord.com/epygazosib.js

So how do I solve this error? Because I saw a similar error someone else had but they are using angular

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed this by simply removing all the comments in all my css files

Answer (score 0):

In my case I made a mistake in the comments in my stylesheet page.
I had something like this

```
/*/*Comment*/
*/.className{
}
```

so removing the comment solved the bug for me.

```
/*Comment*/
.className{
}
```