# How hash classes on NextJS v13.5.2 with tailwind css?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, next.js, tailwind-css, next.js13

I'm trying to hash classes used in a project, Nextjs v13.5.2. For example, the class name .block must be hashed to .wrtbxc. I tried using webpack but it doesn't affect the classes in any way.
My webpack - next.config.js

```
const path = require('path');
const loaderUtils = require('loader-utils');

module.exports = {
  reactStrictMode: false,
  webpack: (config, {dev}) => {
    const rules = config.module.rules
    .find((rule) => typeof rule.oneOf === 'object')
    .oneOf.filter((rule) => Array.isArray(rule.use));

    // if (!dev)
    rules.forEach((rule) => {
      rule.use.forEach((moduleLoader) => {
        if (
          moduleLoader.loader?.includes('css-loader') &&
          !moduleLoader.loader?.includes('postcss-loader') &&
          moduleLoader.options !== undefined &&
          moduleLoader.options.modules !== undefined
        ) {
          console.log(moduleLoader.options.modules);
          moduleLoader.options.localIdentName = '[hash:base64:6]';
          moduleLoader.options.modules.getLocalIdent = (context, _, exportName) => {
            console.log("TEST");
      
            return loaderUtils.getHashDigest(
              Buffer.from(`filePath:${path.relative(context.rootContext, context.resourcePath).replace(/\\+/g, '/')}#className:${exportName}`,),
              'md4','base64', 6,
            ).replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9-_]/g, '_').replace(/^(-?\d|--)/, '_$1');
          };
        }
        
      });
    });
   
    
    return config;
  },
};

localIdentName - not work. For some reason I can't see the console log.
I relied on this thread, but none of the examples worked for me.
[thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74677233/how-to-hash-css-module-class-names-in-nextjs-13)
```

postcss.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {},
  },
}
```

tailwind.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  content: ['./src/components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}', './src/app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}'],
  theme: {
    fontFamily: {
      poppins: ['Poppins', 'sans-serif'],
    },
  },
};
```

Perhaps someone has encountered a similar problem and can help!

Tried to install various plugins for postcss or configure webpack, but all failed.