# how hash classname with nextjs 12.0.8 next.config.js

Tags: javascript, next.js

i'm learm nextjs setting

and try to hash my sass class neme

my next.config.js looking like this

now i't output css classname like [name]__[hash:base64]

why the sassOptions localIdentName didn't work

```js
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  basePath: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_PATH,
  assetPrefix: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_PATH,
  reactStrictMode: true,
  sassOptions: {
    modules: {
      localIdentName: "[hash:base64:5]",
    },
    includePaths: [path.join(__dirname, "styles")],
  },
};
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/69166434/11613622

Comment: so answer is can't overwirt by setting config.js orz