# How to hash tailwind css classes in Nextjs 12

Tags: webpack, next.js, tailwind-css, css-modules, css-loader

I was wondering if there is a way to hash tailwind Css class names on production ? I am trying to hide all of those long Classnames in production.

Comment: It is possible but you will need to configure the build step to do so: what build pipeline do you have?

Comment: @Terry Can you explain to me what do you mean by build pipeline?

Comment: How are you building your app? Are you using some kind of bundler, like webpack, to build it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This answer is helpful to put you on the right track](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69166434/12109726). The problem I was looking to fix is to hash the class names in my code that contains Tailwindcss styles without having to create a new class with the @apply tag. Or use a 3rd party library like twin macro.

Again Thank you @Terry.

Comment: Hey @agoumi, i think the given link only talks about the .module.css files. Do you have any idea how we can uglify/hash the classnames from third-party libraries such as SwiperJs