# Next.js css-loader module classnames do not match between html and css

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css, css-loader

I'am using tailwind css for my css framework, and I'am trying to Hash my tailwind css class using webpack css-loader, the css classes is completed to hash, but the html class is still showing the regullar class

[[image: css]]
[image: html]

this is my next.config.js

```js
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const CssMinimizerPlugin = require("css-minimizer-webpack-plugin");

const nextConfig = {
    reactStrictMode: true,
    // distDir: 'build', custom output build
    webpack: (config, { buildId, dev, isServer, defaultLoaders, webpack }) => {
    console.log("is develop", dev)
        config.module.rules.push(
      {
        test: /\.(css|s[ac]ss)$/i,
        use: [
          !dev ? MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader : 'style-loader',
          {
                        loader: 'css-loader',
                        options: {
                            modules: {
                                localIdentName: "_[hash:base64:5]",
                            },
                        }
                    },
          'postcss-loader',
                    'sass-loader',
        ]
      }
    )
        config.optimization.minimizer.push(
            new CssMinimizerPlugin(),
        )
        config.plugins.push(
      new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
        filename: 'static/css/[contenthash].css'
      }),
    )
        return config
    },
    env: {
        WORDPRESS_BE: process.env.WORDPRESS_BE,
        API_URL: process.env.API_URL,
        ASSET_URL: process.env.ASSET_URL,
        CRYPTO_SECRET_KEY: process.env.CRYPTO_SECRET_KEY,
        API_SAMPLE: process.env.API_SAMPLE,
    },
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

I'am expecting the html class should match with css hash class

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66744765/how-to-hash-css-class-names-in-nextjs

Comment: no thats not working