# How to hash tailwind css classes in Nextjs 13

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css, next.js13

This [method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66744765/how-to-hash-css-class-names-in-nextjs) does not work for tilwind classes, does anyone have a way to hash tilwind classes

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bbyGk.png)

See the picture above, it hashes normal classes, but not tailwind classes
Has anyone found a solution for it?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.